# i can not run ubuntu 22.04 on virtual machine

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, windows, 22.04, virtualization

I use a windows 10 operating system. I have set up ubuntu OS on my virtual box. anytime I start the ubuntu, a dialog box opens that says "failed to open session for virtual machine Linux-Ubuntu 22.04.

[image: output when I try to start the virtual machine]

Answer (score 8):

The message says that virtualization is disabled in the BIOS of your computer. "VT-x is disabled in the BIOS"

Unfortunately the BIOS/UEFI control screens are wildly different between computer makers and even models, so I cannot give you exact instructions, but you must enter your BIOS/UEFI interface at boot, and enable virtualization.